# How to rearrange an array in a particular way in Excel?

Tags: python, r, arrays, excel

I have a data which looks like this:

[image]

I want to rearrange it to get it in this form:
[image]

What will be the most efficient way to do it? My data is very large for doing it by transposing every column. 
Please let me know if the same can be achieved in any other programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R uses [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), so if you have the data in an R matrix, you can just call `c` on that matrix to get the vector you're looking for:

```r
a <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)

a
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    4    7
#> [2,]    2    5    8
#> [3,]    3    6    9

c(a)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>